# Passing through reference a parameter to a function C++

Tags: c++, function, parameters

Let's suppose this code:

```
void function(double &f){

// doing w/e here

}
```

then in the main function:

```
float v;

function(&v);
```

My compiler says that this isn't correct, buy I don't really get why.

On the same topic:

```
void function(float *&f){

// doing w/e here

}
```

then in the main function:

```
float *v;

function(v+5);
```

This is also incorrect for some reason, which I don't get either.

So my question is: Why are those calls incorrect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first example isn't correct because `&v` is a pointer to a float. The function is expecting a reference to a double. A pointer to a float is not a reference to a double. They are incompatible types.

The second example isn't correct because `v+5` is temporary. You can't pass a reference to a non-const temporary.

Comment: Extra note - even if you replace `float` with `double`, a pointer to a `double` is not a reference to a `double`. Actually, these are closely related concepts - a reference is also called a self-dereferencing pointer - but C++ treats them as different types with different behaviours. To specify a pointer type for the parameter, you use `double *f` rather than `double &f`. To pass a reference, you don't need an operator to convert to a reference, you just use `function(v)`.

Comment: One way to think of it - if you use `&` as an operator, it gives you a pointer. If you use `&` in a type, it uses a pointer behind the scenes but you don't deal with the pointer directly yourself.